# Animation along the x-axis in Python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, animation

I have three arrays filled with values which I want to be animate across only the x-axis, how can I do this? I have looked it up, but nothing works so far, wondering if I'm missing something.

I want only one value from each array to be visible at the same time, on the same x-axis.

Let us say that I have these three arrays, created with numpy and zeros:

```
x1 = [1,2,4,5,6,7,9,10]
x2 = [8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
x3 = [16,14,12,10,8,6,4,2]
```

And all I want is for them to move along the same axis in an animation. I don't have any proper code yet, because nothing have worked for me so far. The one undere here is just one of the ones I have tried.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

def update_line(num, data, line):
    line.set_data(data[...,:num])
    return line,

fig1 = plt.figure()

data = np.random.rand(2, 25)
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.title('test')
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, 25, fargs=(data, l),
    interval=50, blit=True)
#line_ani.save('lines.mp4')

fig2 = plt.figure()

x = np.arange(-9, 10)
y = np.arange(-9, 10).reshape(-1, 1)
base = np.hypot(x, y)
ims = []
for add in np.arange(15):
    ims.append((plt.pcolor(x, y, base + add, norm=plt.Normalize(0, 30)),))

im_ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig2, ims, interval=50, repeat_delay=3000,
    blit=True)
#im_ani.save('im.mp4', metadata={'artist':'Guido'})

plt.show()
```

This codes only shows two empty plots for me. And It's much more complicated than what I want, just something I found.

Comment: Animation... in tkinter? Zell graphics? Terminal? Telepathy? Arrays as in... lists? numpy arrays? Nothing works - great, post the nothing and we'll tell you why it doesn't work :)

Comment: I don't know, the simplest option, have tried matplotlib.animation, but it didn't play. It's numpy arrays (zeros). I have only tried examples I have found, and they didn't work, but not what I wanted either. I want one axis.

Comment: Awesome, fine way to start. Post that matplotlib code and we can tell you why it didn't play, that'll be easy and make for a good question!

Comment: I posted something, but it's just something that I found on google.

Comment: Hmm okay, I copy and pasted that into python 3.4 and it did... stuff. Squiggly lines popped up and animated themselves. That doesn't happen for you? What version of python?

Comment: Nothing for me. 2.7 (Spyder)